# Python - Converting roman numerals to integers in a loop, ending script with specific character

Tags: python, loops, exit

Very new to Python, i've managed to do some research on Stack Overflow and using the code below, successfully converted roman numerals to integers.

```
def romanToInt(s):
    d = {'m': 1000, 'd': 500, 'c': 100, 'l': 50, 'x': 10, 'v': 5, 'i': 1}  
    n = [d[i] for i in s.lower() if i in d]  
    return sum([i if i>=n[min(j+1, len(n)-1)] else -i for j,i in enumerate(n)])

print(romanToInt('X'))
```

What I'm struggling to do however is to get this program to continue to run after the output given so the user can enter the next value. I would also like the program to stop when the user enters the character 'Q'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I've done some research on basic loops which I can understand, it's just then incorporating them into code that already exists (such as the code above) which I'm struggling with.

Comment: So, you want to accept input from the user, run the code on that input, and then ask for input again (exiting if they say 'Q')?

Comment: Yes that's correct! I've realised that my code has copied wrong with a few backslashes that shouldn't be there haha

Answer (score 0):

Note: there are *many* ways to do what you're asking—it just depends on how you want it to work/what else you might be doing with it.

Asking for input from the user requires the `input()` function. (It's also a good idea to normalise and test input so it's not case-sensitive and your program doesn't get stuck if users enter something non-sensical, e.g., 'H' here).

If you want to do something until a condition is met (where there's no way of knowing how many iterations that may take), a `while` loop can be a good option.

`while` loops can be tricky, though, because if you don't do something that explicitly breaks out of them, you can create an infinite loop and crash your program.

See below, where I show two examples of `while` loops (the first generally being a better idea than the second).

```py
def romanToInt(s):
    d = {'m': 1000, 'd': 500, 'c': 100, 'l': 50, 'x': 10, 'v': 5, 'i': 1}
    n = [d[i] for i in s.lower() if i in d]
    return sum([i if i>=n[min(j+1, len(n)-1)] else -i for j,i in enumerate(n)])

# this `while` loop explicitly tests a condition each time it runs
text = ''
while text.lower() != 'q':
    print(romanToInt(text))
    text = input("Enter a Roman numeral")



# this `while` loop just runs repeatedly until you explicitly break out of it
# this is often really bad practice
while True:
    # Creates a dialogue box asking the user for input
    text = input("Enter a Roman Numeral")

    if text.lower() != 'q':   # lower() means both 'Q' and 'q' end the loop
        print(romanToInt(text))

    # without the `break` statement inside the `else` block,
    # this creates an infinite loop
    else:
        break
```